# Property of function: why only subset relation for intersection?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a text book about functions. They present a set of properties of functions, one of them:

> Given $f: A \to B$, the following properties hold for any $C_1, C_2 \subseteq A$
>
> a) $f(C_1 \cup C_2) = f(C_1) \cup f(C_2)$
>
> b) $f(C_1 \cap C_2) \subseteq f(C_1) \cap f(C_2)$
>
> ...

The author then adds a remark:

> Part b) only gives a subset relation. The reason is: having $y \in f(C_1)$ and $y \in f(C_2)$ does not necessarily mean that $y$ is the image of the same element. Since $f$ can be many-to-one, it is possible to have $x_1 \in C_1 - C_2$ and $x_2 \in C_2 - C_1$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y$.

There is also an example and I understand in general what is meant, but I can't wrap my head around why we have an 'equals' in the a) property but only a subset-equals in the b) property.

Comment: I also read a proof in the book and the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185965/why-is-fa-cap-b-a-proper-subset-of-fa-cap-fb-why-it-is-proper?rq=1 but I don't get the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $x^2$ and let $C_1= \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ and $C_2= \{ 0, -1, -2, \ldots \}$.

$C_1 \cap C_2 = \{ 0 \}$ and $f(0)= 0^2=0$. Thus: $f (C_1 \cap C_2)= \{ 0 \}$.

But $f(C_1)=f(C_2) = \{ 0, 1, 4, \ldots \}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a\neq b$, $f(\{a\}\cap\{b\})=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, but $f(\{a\})\cap f(\{b\})=\{f(a)\}\neq\emptyset$. So, without injectivity, we don't have equality in b).

There is no such obstacle in a). What is $f(C_1\cup C_2)$? It's the set of those elements of $B$ which are the image by $f$ of an element of $A$ which either belongs to $C_1$ or to $C_2$. And what is $f(C_1)\cup f(C_2)$? Well, it's the same thing.